# my ubuntu laptop is not detecting my headphone

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

I have installed ubuntu 9.10 and if i play songs it is getting played in both laptop and headphone...how can i try to play it only on headphone ....

Comment: You should flag your post for moderator attention and ask for your account to be merged with this one http://superuser.com/questions/172777/my-ubuntu-laptop-is-not-detecting-my-headphone or use same OpenID you used on serverfault.

Comment: You could try telling us what laptop it is...

Answer (score 1):

File a bug

```
ubuntu-bug -p alsa-base
```

Then set the package for the bug (when you get to Launchpad) to be `linux`

This is a driver bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in your sound driver.  Please file it.

```
ubuntu-bug -p alsa-base
```

Once you login on Launchpad, change the package to `linux` (alsa-base is needed to start to get good debugging information added to it)